# Integrating Single sign on of codoforum in yii framework 1

Tags: php, session, yii, single-sign-on

I have just installed codoforum (https://codoforum.com)
and want to use this feature https://codoforum.com/documentation/implementing-codoforum-sso
which consist of integrating Single Sign on in my website.
The website I which to integrate the forum into it is using Yii 1 Framework, I am not familiar with it unfortunately.
Following the documentation of codoforum, I filled in the configuation form and enabled the SSO plugin, what I should do now is complete the file client.php here : https://github.com/evnix/codoforum-sso.
Especially those lines :

```
if (USER_IS_LOGGED_IN) {
    $account['uid'] = USERID; //Your logged in user's userid
    $account['name'] = USERNAME; //Your logged in user's username
    $account['mail'] = EMAILID; //Your logged in user's email id
    $account['avatar'] = ''; //not used as of now
}
```

I filled in those filled manually and it worked, It detects if I am already connected to yii1 website and connect me to the forum using the email I provided.

What I want now is to get those information using the session, I put the file clien.php in the root of my website mywebsite.com/client.php 
I have done some research and I found that this method in siteController is responsible for logging :

```
public function actionLogin() {
    $model = new LoginForm;

    // if it is ajax validation request
    if (isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax'] === 'login-form') {
        echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
        Yii::app()->end();
    }

    // collect user input data
    if (isset($_POST['LoginForm'])) {
        $model->attributes = $_POST['LoginForm'];
        // validate user input and redirect to the previous page if valid
        if ($model->validate() && $model->login()) {
            if (Yii::app()->session['type'] == 1 ) {
                $this->redirect(Yii::app()->homeUrl . 'administration/team');
            }else if (Yii::app()->session['type'] == 2 ) {
                $this->redirect(Yii::app()->homeUrl . 'agenda');
            } else {
                $this->redirect(Yii::app()->homeUrl);
            }
        }
    }
    // display the login form
    $this->render('login', array('model' => $model));
}
```

I have tried to add this code :

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['username']=$model->username;
```

(after :  if ($model->validate() && $model->login()))

and use $_Session in the file client.php but it didn't work.

The problem is that I have no idea how yii1 framework work, and it will take me sometime to be familiar with it, I know that there is session in Yii1, but I don't know how to use it and where to put the file client.php and how can I make it detect the Yii Session.
But if I can use the global session it would be better.

Thank you so much for your time and your answer.